# CSS Shadow on a Div in IE6+

Tags: internet-explorer, css

This is my container:

```
#container {
width: 950px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0px #808080;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0px #808080;
margin-top: 0;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-left: auto;
padding-right: 6px;
padding-left: 6px;
background-color: #FFF;
} 

<div id='container'>

  stuff

</div>
```

How can I get the same shadow effect using IE6+ that I get in Firefox and Chrome?

Comment: You really should visit http://www.ie6countdown.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/).